# jwplayer html5 video fullscreen is not working on iframe embedded

Tags: iframe, html5-video, embed, fullscreen

I will host videos from my server for users. Users can embed videos... Currently I am writing the php script. But I have a problem with embed codes. The problem is, cannot fullscreen on html5... Player support html5 & flash player. If player is flash users can go fullscreen from embed code. But on html5 player can't go fullscreen. Youtube's embed codes can go fullscreen but YouTube uses html5 too. Here is the code that i used:

```
<iframe width="530" height="270" src="http://videohost.tk/embed/0f2c67c9b" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

If you enter the link directly you can go fullscreen. But on iframe you cannot... How can I fix it?

Answer (score 6):

I think your iframe element needs to include the allowfullscreen attribute.

Here is the update code with the new fullscreen attribute as an example:

```
<iframe width="530" height="270" src="http://videohost.tk/embed/0f2c67c9b" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: The above code is working fine for chrome and mozilla how can I do the same for ie?

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to point out: For IE to recognize the `frameborder` attribute, it needs a capital B, as in `frameBorder`. All other browsers seem to recognize both options, so the 'B' is a good failsafe for compatibility. According to the [MSDN docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn312070(v=vs.85).aspx), `allowfullscreen` should work just fine in IE, although that might only pertain to HTML4.